# Did I do original research?

Tags: discussion, original-research

In my answer to the question [Were 48% of American billionaires Jewish in 2014?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36760/were-48-of-american-billionaires-jewish-in-2014/36762#36762) I gave an answer regarding the 2016 numbers. Since it wasn't enough for the OP I went on and did more research and found the list of American billionares from 2014, sadly nobody did a list of the Jewish billionares for that year, and since I'm not going to check the list one by one, I did an upperbound estimate. I took the lists of the year and counted the number of people who were on the list in 2014 but not in 2016. Then I said that in order to get the most number of Jewish American billionaires in 2014 we would need for all the Jewish billionaires of 2016 to be on the list in 2014 as well and for all the people who didn't make the list in 2016 to also be Jewish, thus giving an upper boud of 33%.

I know that this is not the actual number, and the actual number is much lower.

All I did was to take lists count the number of differences and adding that up. I wantto make sure that this isn't concidered original research, I don't think it does as anyone can check this, in my view it's just more elaborate conclusion making, but I want to know what you think about it.

Also, for full transperancy I want to publish the code I used to find the differences in the lists, and I want to know what is the best way to publish it. It's very simple code containing only 8 lines in python:

```
list2016 = ["Bill Gates", "Warren Buffett", "Jeff Bezos", "Mark Zuckerberg", "Larry Ellison", "Michael Bloomberg", "Charles Koch", "David Koch", "Larry Page", "Sergey Brin", "Jim Walton", "Alice Walton", "S. Robson Walton", "Sheldon Adelson", "George Soros", "Phil Knight", "Steve Ballmer", "Forrest Mars Jr", "Jacqueline Mars", "John Mars", "Michael Dell", "Paul Allen", "Carl Icahn", "Laurene Powell Jobs", "Ray Dalio", "James Simons", "Len Blavatnik", "Donald Bren", "Abigail Johnson", "Steve Cohen", "Charles Ergen", "Ronald Perelman", "Stephen Ross", "Patrick Soon-Shiong", "David Tepper", "Thomas Peterffy", "Elon Musk", "Rupert Murdoch", "Lukas Walton", "Eric Schmidt", "Samuel Newhouse Jr", "Philip Anschutz", "Jim Kennedy", "Blair Parry-Okeden", "John Paulson", "Stephen Schwarzman", "Andrew Beal", "John Menard Jr", "Donald Newhouse", "Leonard Lauder", "Dustin Moskovitz", "Jan Koum", "Hank & Doug Meijer", "James Goodnight", "Stanley Kroenke", "Ken Griffin", "Eli Broad", "Thomas Frist Jr", "Herbert Kohler Jr", "Edward Johnson III", "Pierre Omidyar", "Micky Arison", "George Kaiser", "Les Wexner", "David Geffen", "James Chambers", "Katharine Rayner", "Margaretta Taylor", "John Malone", "Travis Kalanick", "Gordon Moore", "Shahid Khan", "Richard LeFrak", "Tom & Judy Love", "John A. Sobrato", "Dennis Washington", "Pauline MacMillan Keinath", "David Green", "Ralph Lauren", "Ted Lerner", "Bruce Halle", "Richard Kinder", "Charles Schwab", "Ray Lee Hunt", "Bruce Kovner", "Jack Taylor", "Trevor Rees-Jones", "Christy Walton", "Harold Hamm", "Diane Hendricks", "Charles Dolan", "Israel Englander", "Tamara Gustavson", "Jerry Jones", "David Shaw", "Jim Davis", "Daniel Gilbert", "Robert Rowling", "Alejandro Santo Domingo", "Andres Santo Domingo", "Carl Cook", "Michael & Marian Ilitch", "Robert Kraft", "Sam Zell", "Daniel Ziff", "Dirk Ziff", "Robert Ziff", "Richard DeVos", "Paul Tudor Jones II", "Whitney MacMillan", "Charles Johnson", "Mark Shoen", "Leon Black", "Ann Walton Kroenke", "George Lucas", "Sumner Redstone", "David Sun", "Donald Trump", "John Tu", "Brian Acton", "Stanley Druckenmiller", "David Duffield", "Jeffery Hildebrand", "Henry Kravis", "Stewart and Lynda Resnick", "Dannine Avara", "John Doerr", "Scott Duncan", "Milane Frantz", "George Roberts", "Reinhold Schmieding", "Randa Williams", "Do Won & Jin Sook Chang", "James Jannard", "Nancy Walton Laurie", "Terrence Pegula", "Jerry Speyer", "Leonard Stern", "Martha Ingram", "Rupert Johnson Jr", "Mary Alice Dorrance Malone", "John Sall", "Jeffrey Skoll", "Sheldon Solow", "Randal Kirk", "John Morris", "H. Ross Perot, Sr.", "Karen Pritzker", "Leandro Rizzuto", "Edward Roski Jr", "Walter Scott Jr", "Phillip Frost", "Jeremy Jacobs, Sr.", "Archie Aldis Emmerson", "Elizabeth Holmes", "Gwendolyn Sontheim Meyer", "Steven Rales", "Ira Rennert", "Julian Robertson Jr", "Harry Stine", "Ronda Stryker", "Peter Buck", "Rick Caruso", "Dan Friedkin", "Kieu Hoang", "Ronald Lauder", "Igor Olenicoff", "Isaac Perlmutter", "Robert Rich Jr", "Haim Saban", "Steven Spielberg", "Steven Udvar-Hazy", "Neil Bluhm", "John Catsimatidis", "Mitchell Rales", "Lynn Schusterman", "Jeff Sutton", "Russ Weiner", "Marc Benioff", "Nathan Blecharczyk", "Bubba Cathy", "Dan Cathy", "Brian Chesky", "Edward DeBartolo Jr", "Joe Gebbia", "Tom Gores", "Jeff Greene", "H. Fisk Johnson", "Imogene Powers Johnson", "S. Curtis Johnson", "Helen Johnson-Leipold", "Winnie Johnson-Marquart", "Bernard Marcus", "Clayton Mathile", "Robert McNair", "Jorge Perez", "Joan Tisch", "Austen Cargill II", "James Cargill II", "Leon G. Cooperman", "Mark Cuban", "Marianne Liebmann", "Kevin Plank", "Anthony Pritzker", "Jay Robert (J.B.) Pritzker", "Ken Fisher", "John Overdeck", "J. Christopher Reyes", "Jude Reyes", "David Siegel", "Frederick Smith", "Donald Sterling", "Roger Wang", "Stephen Bisciotti", "Jack & Laura Dangermond", "Dagmar Dolby", "Bennett Dorrance", "Tilman Fertitta", "Amos Hostetter Jr", "David Rockefeller, Sr.", "Oprah Winfrey", "John Paul DeJoria", "Wilbur Ross Jr", "Howard Schultz", "Robert Bass", "Peter Kellogg", "Bernard Saul II", "Herbert Simon", "Romesh T. Wadhwani", "Riley Bechtel", "Stephen Bechtel Jr", "Andrew & Peggy Cherng", "Robert Duggan", "Kenneth Langone", "James Leprino", "John Middleton", "David Murdock", "Thomas Pritzker", "Peter Thiel", "Arthur Blank", "Doris Fisher", "H. Wayne Huizenga", "Daniel Loeb", "Michael Moritz", "Daniel Och", "A. Jerrold Perenchio", "Henry Samueli", "John Arnold", "David Bonderman", "Bharat & Neerja Sethi Desai", "Tom Golisano", "Henry Hillman", "Stephen Mandel Jr", "Michael Milken", "Gary Rollins", "Randall Rollins", "Robert Smith", "William Wrigley Jr", "Mortimer Zuckerman", "George Bishop", "Jim Breyer", "Chase Coleman III", "Judy Faulkner", "Reid Hoffman", "Douglas Leone", "George Lindemann", "C. Dean Metropoulos", "Sean Parker", "Phillip Ruffin", "Julio Mario Santo Domingo III", "Richard Schulze", "Clemmie Spangler Jr", "Warren Stephens", "Ty Warner", "Dean White", "Steve Wynn", "William Conway Jr", "Daniel D'Aniello", "Barry Diller", "Don Hankey", "Jimmy Haslam", "James Irsay", "John Pritzker", "Penny Pritzker", "Michael Rubin", "Patrick Ryan", "Pat Stryker", "John Arrillaga", "Tom Benson", "John Fisher", "Noam Gottesman", "Joshua Harris", "B. Wayne Hughes", "Min Kao", "Brad Kelley", "Edward Lampert", "Gabe Newell", "Jay Paul", "Richard Peery", "Marc Rowan", "David Rubenstein", "Thomas Siebel", "Paul Singer", "Ted Turner", "Mark Walter", "S. Daniel Abraham", "John Brown", "James Coulter", "David Filo", "Gordon Getty", "Alec Gores", "John Henry", "Stanley Hubbard", "Johnelle Hunt", "Aerin Lauder Zinterhofer", "Joe Mansueto", "Jean (Gigi) Pritzker", "Scott Simplot", "Dan Snyder", "Evan Spiegel", "William Ackman", "Ron Baron", "James Dinan", "Glenn Dubin", "Gerald Ford", "James France", "Bill Gross", "John Kapoor", "Thomas Lee", "Henry Nicholas III", "Bob Parsons", "Robert Pera", "Daniel Pritzker", "Stewart Rahr", "Larry Robbins", "Thomas Secunda", "David Walentas", "Louis Bacon", "Scott Cook", "Rakesh Gangwal", "Joseph Grendys", "Bruce Karsh", "William Koch", "Howard Marks", "Drayton McLane Jr", "Jon Stryker", "Vincent Viola", "Meg Whitman", "Denise York", "George Argyros", "Edward Bass", "Lee Bass", "Sid Bass", "Norman Braman", "James Clark", "Sanford Diller", "Kenneth Feld", "Jeffrey Lurie", "Maggie Magerko", "Arturo Moreno", "Manuel Moroun", "Bobby Murphy", "Jonathan Nelson", "Linda Pritzker", "Jeff Rothschild", "Kavitark Ram Shriram", "Mark Stevens", "Glen Taylor", "John Tyson", "Amy Wyss", "Anita Zucker", "Carol Jenkins Barnett", "Timothy Boyle", "Ray Davis", "W. Herbert Hunt", "Marc Lasry", "Jeffrey Lorberbaum", "Catherine Lozick", "Craig McCaw", "Forrest Preston", "Jennifer Pritzker", "Don Simplot", "Gay Simplot", "Alexander Spanos", "Kelcy Warren", "Richard Yuengling Jr", "O. Francis Biondi", "Victor Fung", "Bill Haslam", "Brian Higgins", "Jim Justice II", "Alexander Karp", "Gary Michelson", "Peter Peterson", "Ben Silbermann", "Charles Simonyi", "Thomas Steyer", "Henry Swieca", "Charlotte Colket Weber", "Jon Yarbrough", "Leslie Alexander", "Nicolas Berggruen", "Ron Burkle", "Sarah MacMillan", "Alexandra Daitch", "John Farber", "Christopher Goldsbury", "David Gottesman", "Ryan Graves", "George Joseph", "Vinod Khosla", "Neal Patterson", "H. Ross Perot Jr", "Phillip Ragon", "Lucy Stitzer", "Katherine Tanner", "Jim Thompson", "Todd Wagner", "Ronald Wanek", "Jerry Yang", "William Young", "Charles Zegar", "Herbert Allen Jr", "Christopher Cline", "Darwin Deason", "David Einhorn", "Frank Fertitta III", "Lorenzo Fertitta", "Robert Fisher", "William Fisher", "Mario Gabelli", "Alan Gerry", "Jonathan Gray", "Jeffrey Gundlach", "Timothy Headington", "B. Wayne Hughes Jr", "Hamilton James", "Eric Lefkofsky", "David Lichtenstein", "Gary Magness", "Billy Joe (Red) McCombs", "Gail Miller", "Nelson Peltz", "Roger Penske", "Nicholas Pritzker II", "Rodney Sacks", "T. Denny Sanford", "Fayez Sarofim", "Edmund Ansin", "David Booth", "Steve Case", "Herb Chambers", "John Edson", "Martha Ford", "Anne Gittinger", "Sidney Kimmel", "Seth Klarman", "James Leininger", "Jerry Reinsdorf", "J. Joe Ricketts", "Brian Roberts", "Alexander Rovt", "Leonard Schleifer", "Wilma Tisch", "Kenny Troutt", "Dan Wilks", "Farris Wilks", "Evan Williams", "Elaine Wynn", "Jim Davis", "Paul Foster", "Reed Hastings", "Richard Hayne", "Stewart Horejsi", "Michael Krasny", "William Lauder", "John Martin", "Charles Munger", "Bruce Nordstrom", "Conrad Prebys", "Michael Price", "Sheryl Sandberg", "Evgeny (Eugene) Shvidler", "Peter Sperling", "Michael Steinhardt", "Bill Alfond", "Peter Alfond", "Susan Alfond", "Ted Alfond", "Thomas Bailey", "William Berkley", "Sara Blakely", "Charles Brandes", "Henry Engelhardt", "Stephen Feinberg", "Dorrance Hamilton", "J. Tomilson Hill", "Irwin Jacobs", "Howard Jenkins", "Summerfield Johnston Jr", "Michael Jordan", "Jane Lauder", "Antony Ressler", "Martin Selig", "Brian Sheth", "E. Joe Shoen", "Kenneth Tuchman", "Thomas Tull", "William F. Austin", "Fred Chang", "Leon Charney", "Robert Citrone", "Jack Dorsey", "Paul Fireman", "J. Christopher Flowers", "Donald Friese", "Ken Grossman", "David Hindawi", "Orion Hindawi", "Daniel Hirschfeld", "Drew Houston", "Thomas Kaplan", "Nancy Lerner", "Norma Lerner", "Randolph Lerner", "Rodney Lewis", "William Macaulay", "Cargill MacMillan III", "John MacMillan", "Martha MacMillan", "William MacMillan", "George Marcus", "Miguel McKelvey", "John Morgridge", "Mark Pincus", "Andrea Reimann-Ciardelli", "Evan Sharp", "William Stone", "Sun Hongbin", "Sanford Weill"];
list2014 = ["A. Jerrold Perenchio", "Abigail Johnson", "Aerin Lauder Zinterhofer", "Alan Gerry", "Alec Gores", "Alexander Knaster", "Alexander Rovt", "Alexander Spanos", "Alfred James Clark", "Alfred Mann", "Alfred Taubman", "Alice Walton", "Amos Hostetter Jr", "Andrea Reimann-Ciardelli", "Andrew & Peggy Cherng", "Andrew Beal", "Aneel Bhusri", "Anita Zucker", "Ann Walton Kroenke", "Anne Cox Chambers", "Anne Gittinger", "Anthony Pritzker", "Archie Aldis Emmerson", "Arthur Blank", "Arturo Moreno", "Austen Cargill II", "B. Wayne Hughes", "Barbara Carlson Gage", "Barry Diller", "Bennett Dorrance", "Bernard Marcus", "Bernard Saul II", "Bharat Desai", "Bill Gates", "Bill Gross", "Bill Marriott Jr", "Billy Joe (Red) McCombs", "Blair Parry-Okeden", "Bob Parsons", "Brad Kelley", "Brian Acton", "Brian Higgins", "Brian Roberts", "Bruce Halle", "Bruce Karsh", "Bruce Kovner", "Bruce Nordstrom", "C. Dean Metropoulos", "C. James Koch", "Carl Icahn", "Carol Jenkins Barnett", "Catherine Lozick", "Charles Brandes", "Charles Butt", "Charles Dolan", "Charles Ergen", "Charles Johnson", "Charles Koch", "Charles Munger", "Charles Schwab", "Charles Simonyi", "Charles Zegar", "Charlotte Colket Weber", "Chase Coleman III", "Christopher Burch", "Christopher Cline", "Christopher Goldsbury", "Christy Walton", "Clayton Mathile", "Clemmie Spangler Jr", "Craig McCaw", "Dagmar Dolby", "Dan Friedkin", "Dan Snyder", "Dan Wilks", "Daniel D'Aniello", "Daniel Gilbert", "Daniel Harrison III", "Daniel Hirschfeld", "Daniel Loeb", "Daniel Och", "Daniel Pritzker", "Daniel Ziff", "Dannine Avara", "Darwin Deason", "David Bonderman", "David Booth", "David Duffield", "David Einhorn", "David Filo", "David Geffen", "David Gottesman", "David Green", "David Koch", "David Murdock", "David Rockefeller Sr", "David Rubenstein", "David Shaw", "David Sun", "David Tepper", "David Walentas", "Dean White", "Denise York", "Dennis Washington", "Diane Hendricks", "Dirk Ziff", "Don Hankey", "Donald Bren", "Donald Hall", "Donald Newhouse", "Donald Sterling", "Donald Trump", "Doris Fisher", "Drayton McLane Jr", "Drew Houston", "Dustin Moskovitz", "Edmund Ansin", "Edward Bass", "Edward DeBartolo Jr", "Edward Johnson III", "Edward Lampert", "Edward Roski Jr", "Edward Stack", "Elaine Marshall", "Elaine Wynn", "Eli Broad", "Elon Musk", "Eric Lefkofsky", "Eric Schmidt", "Evan Williams", "Evgeny (Eugene) Shvidler", "Farris Wilks", "Fayez Sarofim", "Forrest Mars Jr", "Frank Fertitta III", "Fred Chang", "Fred DeLuca", "Frederick Smith", "Gabe Newell", "Gary Burrell", "Gary Magness", "Gary Michelson", "Gayle Cook", "George Argyros", "George Bishop", "George Joseph", "George Kaiser", "George Lindemann", "George Lucas", "George Roberts", "George Soros", "Gerald J. Ford", "Glen Taylor", "Glenn Dubin", "Gordon Getty", "Gordon Moore", "Gwendolyn Sontheim Meyer", "H. Fisk Johnson", "H. Ross Perot Jr", "H. Ross Perot Sr", "H. Wayne Huizenga", "Haim Saban", "Hamilton James", "Hank & Doug Meijer", "Harold Hamm", "Harry Stine", "Helen Johnson-Leipold", "Henry Engelhardt", "Henry Hillman", "Henry Kravis", "Henry Nicholas III", "Henry Samueli", "Henry Swieca", "Herbert Allen Jr", "Herbert Kohler Jr", "Herbert Louis", "Herbert Simon", "Hoang Kieu", "Howard Marks", "Howard Schultz", "Igor Olenicoff", "Imogene Powers Johnson", "Ira Rennert", "Irwin Jacobs", "Isaac Larian", "Isaac Perlmutter", "Israel Englander", "J. Christopher Reyes", "J. Joe Ricketts", "Jack Dangermond", "Jack Dorsey", "Jack Taylor", "Jacqueline Mars", "James Cargill II", "James Clark", "James Coulter", "James Dinan", "James France", "James Goodnight", "James Irsay", "James Jannard", "James Leininger", "James Leprino", "James Simons", "Jan Koum", "Jane Lauder", "Jay Robert (J.B.) Pritzker", "Jean (Gigi) Pritzker", "Jeff Bezos", "Jeff Greene", "Jeff Rothschild", "Jeff Sutton", "Jeffery Hildebrand", "Jeffrey Lorberbaum", "Jeffrey Skoll", "Jennifer Pritzker", "Jeremy Jacobs Sr", "Jerry Jones", "Jerry Speyer", "Jerry Yang", "Jim Breyer", "Jim Davis", "Jim Justice II", "Jim Kennedy", "Jim Thompson", "Jim Walton", "Jimmy Haslam", "Do Won & Jin Sook Chang", "Joan Tisch", "Joe Jamail Jr", "Joe Mansueto", "John A. Sobrato", "John Arnold", "John Arrillaga", "John Brown", "John Catsimatidis", "John Doerr", "John Edson", "John Farber", "John Fisher", "John Henry", "John Kapoor", "John Malone", "John Mars", "John Menard Jr", "John Morgridge", "John Morris", "John Paul DeJoria", "John Paulson", "John Pritzker", "John Sall", "John Tu", "Johnelle Hunt", "Jon Huntsman", "Jon Stryker", "Jonathan Gray", "Jonathan Nelson", "Jonathan Oringer", "Jorge Perez", "Joseph Grendys", "Josephine Louis", "Joshua Harris", "Joyce Raley Teel", "Jude Reyes", "Judy Faulkner", "Julian Robertson Jr", "Karen Pritzker", "Kavitark Ram Shriram", "Kelcy Warren", "Ken Fisher", "Ken Griffin", "Kenneth Feld", "Kenneth Langone", "Kenneth Tuchman", "Kenny Troutt", "Kevin Plank", "Kirk Kerkorian", "Larry Ellison", "Larry Page", "Larry Robbins", "Laurene Powell Jobs", "Leandro Rizzuto", "Lee Bass", "Len Blavatnik", "Leon Black", "Leon Charney", "Leon G. Cooperman", "Leonard Lauder", "Leonard Schleifer", "Leonard Stern", "Leslie Wexner", "Linda Pritzker", "Lorenzo Fertitta", "Louis Bacon", "Lynn Schusterman", "Malcolm Glazer", "Manuel Moroun", "Marc Benioff", "Marc Lasry", "Marc Rowan", "Marianne Liebmann", "Marilyn Carlson Nelson", "Mario Gabelli", "Mark Cuban", "Mark Pincus", "Mark Shoen", "Mark Stevens", "Mark Vadon", "Mark Zuckerberg", "Martha Ingram", "Mary Alice Dorrance Malone", "Matt & Dan Walsh", "Meg Whitman", "Michael & Marian Ilitch", "Michael Bloomberg", "Michael Dell", "Michael Jaharis", "Michael Kors", "Michael Krasny", "Michael Milken", "Michael Moritz", "Michael Price", "Michael Rubin", "Michael Steinhardt", "Micky Arison", "Milane Frantz", "Min Kao", "Mitchell Jacobson", "Mitchell Rales", "Mortimer Zuckerman", "Nancy Walton Laurie", "Neal Patterson", "Neil Bluhm", "Nelson Peltz", "Nicholas Pritzker II", "Nicholas Woodman", "Nicolas Berggruen", "Noam Gottesman", "Norman Braman", "O. Francis Biondi", "Oprah Winfrey", "Pat Stryker", "Patrick McGovern", "Patrick Ryan", "Patrick Soon-Shiong", "Paul Allen", "Paul Foster", "Paul Singer", "Paul Tudor Jones II", "Pauline MacMillan Keinath", "Penny Pritzker", "Peter Buck", "Peter Kellogg", "Peter Peterson", "Peter Sperling", "Peter Thiel", "Phil Knight", "Philip Anschutz", "Philip Falcone", "Phillip Frost", "Phillip Ragon", "Phillip Ruffin", "Pierre Omidyar", "Ralph Lauren", "Randa Williams", "Randal Kirk", "Ray Dalio", "Ray Davis", "Ray Irani", "Ray Lee Hunt", "Reid Hoffman", "Reinhold Schmieding", "Richard Chilton Jr", "Richard DeVos", "Richard Hayne", "Richard Kinder", "Richard LeFrak", "Richard Marriott", "Richard Peery", "Richard Rainwater", "Richard Scaife", "Richard Schulze", "Richard Yuengling Jr", "Riley Bechtel", "Robert Bass", "Robert Citrone", "Robert Duggan", "Robert Fisher", "Robert Kraft", "Robert McNair", "Robert Pera", "Robert Piccinini", "Robert Rich Jr", "Robert Rowling", "Robert Ziff", "Rodney Lewis", "Roger Penske", "Roger Wang", "Romesh T. Wadhwani", "Ron Baron", "Ron Burkle", "Ronald Lauder", "Ronald Perelman", "Ronald Wanek", "Ronda Stryker", "Rupert Johnson Jr", "Rupert Murdoch", "Ryan Kavanaugh", "S. Curtis Johnson", "S. Daniel Abraham", "S. Robson Walton", "S. Truett Cathy", "Sam Zell", "Samuel Newhouse Jr", "Sara Blakely", "Scott Cook", "Scott Duncan", "Sean Parker", "Sergey Brin", "Seth Klarman", "Shahid Khan", "Sheldon Adelson", "Sheldon Solow", "Sheryl Sandberg", "Sid Bass", "Sidney Kimmel", "Stanley Druckenmiller", "Stanley Hubbard", "Stanley Kroenke", "Stephen Bechtel Jr", "Stephen Bisciotti", "Stephen Mandel Jr", "Stephen Ross", "Stephen Schwarzman", "Steve Ballmer", "Steve Case", "Steve Cohen", "Steve Wynn", "Steven Rales", "Steven Spielberg", "Steven Udvar-Hazy", "Stewart and Lynda Resnick", "Stewart Horejsi", "Stewart Rahr", "Sumner Redstone", "Sun Hongbin", "Susan Hirt Hagen", "Tamara Gustavson", "Ted Lerner", "Ted Turner", "Terrence Pegula", "Thomas Bailey", "Thomas Frist Jr", "Thomas Kaplan", "Thomas Lee", "Thomas Peterffy", "Thomas Pritzker", "Thomas Secunda", "Thomas Siebel", "Thomas Steyer", "Tilman Fertitta", "Timothy Boyle", "Timothy Headington", "Todd Wagner", "Tom & Judy Love", "Tom Benson", "Tom Golisano", "Tom Gores", "Tor Peterson", "Tory Burch", "Trevor Rees-Jones", "Ty Warner", "Victor Fung", "Vincent McMahon", "Vinod Khosla", "W. Herbert Hunt", "Walter Scott Jr", "Warren Buffett", "Warren Stephens", "Whitney MacMillan", "Wilbur Ross Jr", "William Ackman", "William Conway Jr", "William Erbey", "William Fisher", "William Ford Sr", "William Koch", "William Macaulay", "William Moncrief Jr", "William Wrigley Jr", "Wilma Tisch", "Winnie Johnson-Marquart"];
count = 0;
for name in list2014:
    if not name in list2016:
        count = count + 1;
        print(name);
print(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

It *is* original research, however for very simple things, that do not require expertise we've been lenient in the past.

However, there is a small mistake in your answer. I don't think it matters substantially, but you can never mix 2016 data with 2014 data without making assumptions: for example that people never stop or become being Jew, or that the information known about is the same across the two years.

Suppose a significant number of people in the Jew list for 2016 were not known to be Jew in 2014; this would be interesting but this information would be lost by your method. Your numbers would also be slightly off.

As long as you:

- list the actual assumptions
- don't assume certainty when you can't

you are going to be fine.

E.g.:

- if the list of Jews in 2014 is not significantly different from the one in 2016, then...

or

- this calculation is suggestive that...

are fine, but

- as my calculation shows, the facts are that...

is not.

Comment: So I don't get, do you think is is ok or not? Also which part is the original research?

Comment: I don't think your current answer is OK, because it makes unwarranted assumptions, but the problem is not the *counting* itself.

Comment: The "count" in a title was an attempt at humor, the question is about the entire addition, including the assumption. Why do you think that it's unwarranted?

Comment: Also, please note that the assumption is not that all old billionaires are Jews, but that **at most** they are all Jews. My answer doesn't give an '=' but a '<'.

Comment: You used a method in your answer which has hidden assumptions which you have ignored and jumped to conclusions. This is *exactly* the reason why we don't allow OR. It's tricky to get right, and people do not accept any criticism.